# "Either A or B" dependency in Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

In one of my packages, I semi-recently added an overly strict dependency version constraint to work around a bug in that particular version of the package. However, as new versions of other packages have been released, this is now causing dependency conflicts for some of my users. One of them helpfully suggested to replace the current, overly strict, constraint `zip-archive == 0.2` with something along the lines of `(zip-archive <= 0.2.3 && binary >= 0.5) || (zip-archive >= 0.2.3.1 && binary >= 0.7)` - that is, depend either on A or on B, and we don't really care which one.

Is there a way to express this in Cabal?

Comment: maybe add more than one library (I guess it's a library) sections with the different combinations? ... yeah I know this sucks

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case it's a binary.

Comment: it would be a mess anyway - I think you have to give this the modified .cabal file then (ofc: it's haskell so there is a chance that there somewhere is a reasearch project that implemented just that - but for vanilla cabal I don't think there is) - just think of it: cabal(-install) is used to install the packages too - so if there are "or"s - what package-version to install? (I guess some kind with *minimal impact*?)

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of afraid that this would be the issue. Someone should look into using an SMT solver for Cabal dependencies! :P

Comment: Seems like you can make a flag ([example](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/c9f3cc506f67b5136473dc191ea205800bbeddb7/aeson.cabal), how it is rendered on hackage - https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.4), so users will specify what dependencies they want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I haven't verified this, I think you can do it using a flag:

```
flag someName
  default: True

library
  if flag(someName)
    build-depends:
      zip-archive >= 0.2.3.1,
      binary >= 0.7
  else
    build-depends:
      zip-archive <= 0.2.3,
      binary >= 0.5
```

The solver will pick the branch that makes the overall constraint problem solvable.

Comment: I ended up getting rid of the dependency altogether, but this trick does indeed seem to work. Thanks!